# Bokeh tutorial for using slickgrid

Tags: python, slickgrid, bokeh

The recent release of bokeh 0.7 has slickgrid support. I am new to Bokeh. And I don't know where to start without examples. Did some search online, except an animated demo of bokeh slickgrid in action, I could not find the example codes.

So **specific** question first:

--> How can I find out how to use this feature. Is there a bokeh slickgrid tutorial/document?

And the **general** question:

--> Where to start when a new Bokeh function becomes available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we are working on adding even more examples and docs and hopefully some videos on a new Youtube channel, but its a lot of work, as you can imagine. :) In the mean time, here is one example that uses the new data table with a static document:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/glyphs/data_tables.py

and here is a slightly more complicated example that has some widgets and uses the `bokeh-server`

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/glyphs/data_tables_server.py

Note, both of these use the "low-level" glyphs API, we still need to work up some examples using some of the higher level API.

Comment: It is worth mentioning here that Bryan is a/the principle author of  Bokeh.